# ExceptionMapper method toResponse not invoke

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

toResponse method of ExceptionMapper class is not invoke.

Code

```
public class PortalExceptionMapper implements  ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% testing product%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
    return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .entity(prepareMessage(exception))
            .type("application/json")
            .build();


}

private String prepareMessage(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
    String msg = "";
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> cv : exception.getConstraintViolations()) {
        msg+=cv.getPropertyPath()+" "+cv.getMessage()+"\n";
    }
    return msg;
}
```

}

=======================================================

This exceptionMapper class register on ResourcesConfig

```
public class PortalApp extends ResourceConfig 
{
public PortalApp()
{
    register(AccessRequestFilter.class);
    packages("org.learn");      
    register(JacksonFeature.class);
    register(PortalExceptionMapper.class);
    register(PortalJackson.class);
    register(PortalFilter.class);


}
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980696/exceptionmapper-cant-be-invoke?noredirect=1#comment113137546_63980696 Can you check my question please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark your class with @Provider:

```
@Provider
public class PortalExceptionMapper implements  ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {...}
```

Comment: I am using import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
@Provider
public class PortalExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {


but it not work.

Comment: What exception do you throw?

Comment: Try with ExceptionMapper<Exception>

Comment: There is no error occur.
ExceptionMapper method toResponse not invoke

Comment: What you're trying to achieve if there is no error?